# WPF command how to get all necessary info to add to the correct list item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am developing a User Control and would like to know how the correct way would be to implement it if I want to comply to the MVVM Model.

I shorten my real use case to an example:
There is a configuration view called config.xaml and a view model I call ConfigVM. For this example I believe the Model is not relevant but if you need it for your answer I would call it ConfigData.

In this view there is a combobox with string values. The combo box selected valua should be added to a selected item of a list box. To execute this action there is a button "Add name" besides the combobox. Bound with a command.
But: The selected item of the listbox is defined by a selected item of a primary list box. So this is a bit cascading.
I hope the picture brings some light to the setup.
[image: User Control setup]

the mvvm class is coded like this (shortend to get the idea):

```
class ConfigVM
{
    public ObservableList list1{}
}

class List1ItemVm
{
    public ObservableList List2{}
}

class List2Item
{
    public string Name{}
}
```

The binding for the button currently is (which is not working of course):

```
      Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox}"
```

My question is: How shall I get the receiving list2 selected item to add the combobox selected item to it?
From the command I get the name of the combobox selected item as parameter, but at the point inside the command I don't know which list I shall add this to.

Ann.: I added the cascading lists because it is my scenario and makes it more difficult for me to get the correct items and do binding in xaml.

Possibilites i can think of:

1. Should I reference the view inside the ViewModel? To find out the selected Item of list2?
   This is probably a break to the MVVM Pattern? correct?
   (I could set the view as a parent of the VM when the DataContext is set on DataContextChanged.)
2. Or can I bind it in a way where I have all the information available to automatically somehow magic add the Name to the list2item? (how?)
3. Should I try a multibinding. I haven't used it before and I have the feeling it is a bit overly complicated for this "easy" problem. (Writing converter etc.)

**Update**
Some more infos from real code:
Combobox:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Grid.Column="1">
  <ComboBox x:Name="comboSymbols"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            MinWidth="150"
            Margin="10,10,0,0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SymbolsAvailable}"
            dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
            Height="22"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
          <TextBlock Text=" | " />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Unit}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
  <Button Content="Symbol hinzufügen"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          MinWidth="75"
          Margin="10,10,0,0"
          Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboSymbols}"
          Height="22"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</StackPanel>
```

List 2:

```
<ListBox x:Name="symbolsListBox"
         Grid.Column="1"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="175"
         Margin="26,39,0,0"
         Grid.Row="1"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="137"
         DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=channelListBox}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Symbols}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" | " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Unit}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

List1:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="channelListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Width="170"
           Margin="10,10,0,10"
           ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelCollection}"
           dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
           dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
           dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"
           Height="504">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gid}" />
          <TextBlock Text=" | " />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you post your non-shortened VM as well as your XAML?  This question might be considered **too-broad**?

Comment: 1)  No, never. See 2).   2) Yes.  You can have your V databind to a `SelectedSomething` in your VM and vice-versa when adding.

Comment: I don't see the possibility for 2). I have a binding to the list selected item from the combo. I can try to post some more code. but what do you mean by vice-versa. A binding back to the list? That also has a binding to the first list. (one minute. I am gathering more infos for an update with code).

Comment: WPF binding can be _one-way_; _two-way_ to name but two.  That means that the selected item in a `listbox` can be bound to a VM and that the VM can **also** _set the selected item_.  When you consider the VM is responsible for filling the `listbox` the rest is easy.

Comment: You mean I can add a property SelectedItem to the VM and bind it to the selectedItem of the list? Then reference it in code? That could work. Would that be MVVM pattern?

Comment: Thanks for the code update.  So it looks like your many of your elements in your XAML are referencing one another particularly `SelectedItem` and your AddCommand which uses a parameter so the VM sadly is not seeing it directly in all cases.

Comment: _"You mean I can add a property SelectedItem to the VM and bind it"_ - yes that's correct and yes that's still MVVM.  There's also nothing wrong with XAML elements referring to one another (that's the power) but in this case I probably would have had a VM property for `SelectedItem`

Comment: So I add SelectedItemList1 and SelectedItemList2. That sounds good and I will try that. Mind to post it as an answer? I didn't have that solution on my scope. I started WPF just some weeks ago and try to learn best practices.

Comment: Done.  Not a problem.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**Note**: This answer is an aggregate of the conversation had under the question with the OP.

---

> Should I reference the view inside the ViewModel? To find out the selected Item of list2?
>   This is probably a break to the MVVM Pattern? correct?
>   (I could set the view as a parent of the VM when the DataContext is set on DataContextChanged.)

In pure MVVM the viewmodel (VM) should be decoupled from the view (V) and so should not contain a reference to the underlying V's class object.  So no.

> Or can I bind it in a way where I have all the information available to automatically somehow magic add the Name to the list2item? (how?)

Yes. You can have your V databind to a **SelectedSomething** in your VM and vice-versa when adding.

WPF binding can be *one-way; two-way* to name but two. That means that the selected item in a `listbox` can be bound to a VM and that the VM can also set the selected item. When you consider the VM is responsible for filling the `listbox` the rest is easy.

So it looks like your many of your elements in your XAML are referencing one another particularly `SelectedItem` and your **AddCommand** which uses a parameter so the VM sadly is not seeing it directly in all cases.

> "You mean I can add a property SelectedItem to the VM and bind it"

Yes that's correct and yes that's still MVVM. There's also nothing wrong with XAML elements referring to one another (that's the power) but in this case I probably would have had a VM property for SelectedItem.

### Would you like to know more?

- *[WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)*
- *[5: Implementing the MVVM Pattern Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx)*